# Getting which interface received each packet when reading pcap files

Tags: c, networking, wireshark, pcap

I'm using multiple network taps to listen on some links of an ethernet network. They're are connected to a computer on which I capture all the traffic that passes through those links, and I save that capture in order to analyze it with a C program that I wrote using pcap library.

My problem is that I can't retrieve the interface on which each packets have been captured. This information is not present in the struct pcap_pkthdr. It should though be possible to get that information using the pcap library as wireshark indicates it on its user interface.

Would someone know how to find this information about packets stored in pcap files?

Comment: It is not really stored in pcap files, but it can often be derived from the l2-header. This of course doesn't apply to incoming packets to broadcast/multicast or when the interface is in promiscuous mode

Comment: Thanks for the answer!                                                 I'm spying for example on 2 links, one between a computer and a switch, and one between the same switch and a second computer. So if I send a frame from the first to the second computer, the two captured frame (more like the same frame captured two times, before and after the switch) will have the same ethernet header so it won't help me to find which "interfaces" (which network tap) captured which frame.

Comment: Correct. Dump the links to different filenames to distinguish between them.

Comment: Yeah that's a clever workaround, thanks! I actually never saw the option "marked packets only" when yoh save a wireshark capture as I'm a newbie to wireshark. Thanks a lot!